# No Launcher activity found, The launch will only sync the application package on the device

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

I got this warning from console when running my application on emulator

```
No Launcher activity found!
The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
```

In fact i have declared an activity as the main launcer in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
        <activity
            android:name=".myActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I don't need any other intent-filter to use on that activity.. just basic main and launcher

What's the reason? Please give me a solution..

Comment: put full androidManifest file

Comment: myActivity its case sensitive so if your class has name MyActivity it won't work. check first class names.

Comment: as Samir said need complete  androidManifest file

Answer (score 4):

If the launcher activity is in another package, you will need to specify that as well. 
For instance, from one of my personal projects:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MainScreen"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The MainScreen.java is in the activities package. Also, check spelling for upper or lower case letters.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you must have "android.intent.action.MAIN" specified immediately before "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER". I encountered the same issue as you when I had the following:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

The issue was resolved only when I re-orderd as follows:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

In all normal circumstances, listen to what the other guy(s) said.

I was able to replicate your issue using a Mac Book Pro & Eclipse Indigo. when you create your android project, you MUST have Eclipse start you off with a templated activity (like a blank activity). if you don't, and you try to add an activity to your manifest later, Eclipse just derps and can't find the launcher. (i looked at other manifest files and i can't see any differences. i really don't think it's your poor manifest's fault in this special case.)

here's your lazy easy fix:

start a new project, and copy over all the files (make sure you back up ur files first, in case you delete something wrong or mess up the ordering)

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse Indigo, open Run Configurations windows, click the project and use launch default activity on Android tab, choose Automatically pick compatible device...and apply.